# filters don't work on a certain image

Tags: gimp, effects

I found a PNG pixelated image on the net (16*16) and under the "Filters" blur effect are grayed out and unclickable. Even when I size it up it still doesn't get blurred (which happens by default). I'm using a Gimp version on Edubuntu titled "2.2.13-1ubuntu4.4 (gimp)" and I'm not able to install a newer one. So far this is the only image where some features doesn't seem to work. I reopened it a couple of times and it's always the same. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some effects like *blur* can not be applied on indexed formats. You will have to change the image mode to RGB first.

In Gimp this is done by selecting *Image > Mode > RGB* from the top menu bar.

Comment: That was the problem, thanks :) (I'm on an outdated browser so hopefully I checked "best answer")